How to Increase the Width of Bars in Syncfusion Flutter Chart's Column Series?
I'm trying to customize the appearance of the column bars in a Syncfusion Flutter chart. Specifically, I want to increase the width of the bars, but I'm not sure how to adjust it.
Here's the code I currently have:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(_ChartApp());
}

class _ChartApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: _MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class _MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<_MyHomePage> {
  late TooltipBehavior _tooltip;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tooltip = TooltipBehavior(enable: true);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Syncfusion Flutter Chart with Gradient Colors'),
      ),
      body: SfCartesianChart(
        primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(),
        primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(minimum: 0, maximum: 20, interval: 3),
        margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
        tooltipBehavior: _tooltip,
        series: _buildColumnSeries(),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<ColumnSeries<_ChartData, String>> _buildColumnSeries() {
    final data = [
      _ChartData('Jan', 8, [Color(0xFFFF0000), Color(0x17C1884F)]),
      _ChartData('Feb', 14, [Color(0xFF0000FF), Color(0xD00B5E2)]),
      _ChartData('Mar', 10, [Color(0xFF008000), Color(0x1890EE90)]),
      _ChartData('Apr', 13, [Color(0xFF800080), Color(0x12FFC0CB)]),
      _ChartData('May', 2, [Color(0xFF008080), Color(0x2400FFFF)]),
    ];

    return data.map((entry) {
      return ColumnSeries<_ChartData, String>(
        dataSource: [entry],
        xValueMapper: (_ChartData data, _) => data.x,
        yValueMapper: (_ChartData data, _) => data.y,
        width: 1, // Here I set the width of the bars
        spacing: 0.0,
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: entry.colors,
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
      );
    }).toList();
  }
}

class _ChartData {
  final String x;
  final double y;
  final List<Color> colors;

  _ChartData(this.x, this.y, this.colors);
}


In the code above, I'm using the ColumnSeries for the chart, and I set the width property to 1. However, I would like to increase the width of the bars.
What I have tried:

I tried changing the width property to higher values, but the bars do not seem to increase in width.

I also tried adjusting the spacing and other properties, but that doesn't seem to solve the problem either.


I want to show this type but the column is a different colour.

Question: How can I properly increase the width of the bars in this ColumnSeries when using the Syncfusion Flutter chart library?

The problem is that you are creating one chart for each entry of your data set.
Create a single ColumnSeries for your entire dataset.

But in a single-column series, I do not provide multiple colours.

I see. Try what I suggested, but try using the pointColorMapping to set the color of each column. I think you won't be able to set a gradient though. Looks like there is a limitation on the library to achieve what you want :(

Or maybe you can try using this: https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/CartesianSeries/onCreateRenderer.html
